# Multiprocessing append to pool without map

Tags: python, multiprocessing, append

I have a function to encrypt a bunch of strings to md5 and inside of it, I have a pool which I create.

Main.py

```
config = ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

possibleCharacters = "abcd"

def mapped_loop_digit(args):
     loop_digit(*args, is_pool=True)

def loop_digit(current_str, place, strings, hashes, is_outer=False, is_pool=False):
     if place == config.getint("string_creation", "length_for_new_process"):
         current_strings = list()

     for character in possibleCharacters:
         current_str[place] = character

         if is_outer and config.getboolean("development", "minor_logging"):
             print("Outer character maker at", possibleCharacters.index(character) + 1, "in", len(possibleCharacters))

         elif is_pool and config.getboolean("development", "pool_minor_logging"):
             print("Outest in pool character maker for process", multiprocessing.current_process()._identity[0],
              "at", possibleCharacters.index(character) + 1, "in", len(possibleCharacters), "with character as",
              str(character) + ". Current string is", current_str)

    if place == 0:
        string = "".join(_character for _character in current_str)
        hashes.append(hashlib.md5(string.encode()).hexdigest())
        strings.append(string)

    elif place == config.getint("string_creation", "length_for_new_process"):
        current_strings.append(current_str.copy())

    else:
        loop_digit(current_str, place - 1, strings, hashes)

     if place == config.getint("string_creation", "length_for_new_process"):
         args = list()
         print("Starting a new pool")
         for string in current_strings:
             args.append([string, place - 1, strings, hashes])

         with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=config.getint("string_creation", "processes")) as pool:
             pool.map(mapped_loop_digit, args)
             pool.close()
             pool.join()

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
all_strings = manager.list("")
all_hashes = manager.list("")

loop_digit(["", "", "", ""], 4 - 1, all_strings, all_hashes, is_outer=True)
```

config.ini

```
[development]
minor_logging = 1
pool_minor_logging = 1

[string_creation]
processes = 3
length_for_new_process = 3
```

At the moment I have a list called current_strings and append to it in the middle of the program, then at the end, I loop through it and create a list of the arguments to then map it to a separate function and then run the original function again. Is there an easier way to do this so I can just append to the pool instead of the list.

Comment: you can use `pool = multiprocessing.Pool()` to create pool only once at start and later you can use many times `pool.map()` (without `pool.close()`). But you should use `pool.map_async()` and it will not wait for the end of `map` and you can run another `pool.map_async()`. Poll has also other functions like `apply_async` to add single processes for single item instead of using `map` with list of many items. You will have to also `use `it = pool.map_async()` and `it.wait()` to keep program running until it finish processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create `Pool` as

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
```

without `pool.close()` `pool.join()` then you can use `pool` many times in different places (in different functions).

If you use `map_async()` instead of `map()` then you don't have to wait for the end of processes and you can add more processes using next `map_async()` and `pool` will manage all processes together.

You can also use `apply_async` to add single proces to existing `pool`.

Because `map_async` and `apply_async` doesn't wait for end of processses so you have to control it using `wait()` before exit program

```
it1 = pool.map_async(...)
it2 = pool.map_async(...)
it3 = pool.apply_async(...)

# ... code ...

it1.wait()
it2.wait()
it3.wait()
```

or you have to use (both) at the end

```
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

If you don't use it then program may exit before processes will be finished and it will terminate them.

---

Minimal working example

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def fun(number):
    for x in range(3):
        time.sleep(.2)
        print(number, 'loop:', x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)

    print("map [1,2,3]")
    it1 = pool.map_async(fun, [1,2,3])

    print("map ['A', 'B', 'C']")
    it2 = pool.map_async(fun, ['A', 'B', 'C'])

    print("single work X")
    it3 = pool.apply_async(fun, 'X')

    print("single work Y")
    it4 = pool.apply_async(fun, 'Y')

    # wait for the end of processes

    print('wait for the end of processes')

    #it1.wait()
    #it2.wait()
    #it3.wait()
    #it4.wait()

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print('exit')
```

Comment: I added information about `pool.close()` , `pool.join()` at the end of program - instead of all of `wait()`